# R package openxlsx and gradient

Tags: r

I use the R package "openxlsx" and the "conditionalFormatting" function. I can apply different colors to cells in the excel output file according to selected values.

Now I'd like to apply a color gradient to a column in my dataframe instead of preselected color values.

Is it possible with "conditionalFormatting" ?